# htaccess - Rewrite requests with .png, .jpg to one file

Tags: image, .htaccess, url-rewriting, png, jpeg

stackoverflow

Today i am coming here with small problem, that is i need (more likely want) to rewrite all incoming requests like:

```
GET /51284.jpg
```

into:

```
GET /52814.png
```

all to one file
- `e.php`

I tried lot of ways but none of them worked.

Yours,
XeJuicY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mister XeJuicY,

You could use a `RewriteRule` like:

```
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^([0-9]+).jpg$ /e.php?image=$1.png [R=301,L]
```

Comment: And I realised i wrote it bad... I need to put all requests with no extension to .png file. Just one file...

Comment: Got it using Your, code... Thank you very much, this worked.
RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ /e.php [R=301,L]
that e.php file generates output as .png